# Cannot move file because NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, file, file-exists

I use this code to list files into directory and move it based on a found value.

```java
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {

        File directoryPath = new File("C:\\csv\\nov");
        // Create a new subfolder called "processed" into source directory
        try {
            Path processedFolderPath = Path.of(directoryPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/processed");
            if (!Files.exists(processedFolderPath) || !Files.isDirectory(processedFolderPath)) {
                Files.createDirectory(processedFolderPath);
            }

            Path invalidFilesFolderPath = Path.of(directoryPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/invalid_files");
            if (!Files.exists(invalidFilesFolderPath) || !Files.isDirectory(invalidFilesFolderPath)) {
                Files.createDirectory(invalidFilesFolderPath);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        FilenameFilter textFileFilter = (dir, name) -> {
            String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
            if (lowercaseName.endsWith(".csv")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
        // List of all the csv files
        File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles(textFileFilter);
        System.out.println("List of the text files in the specified directory:");

        for(File file : filesList) {

            try {
                try (var br = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16)){
                    List<CsvLine> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(br)
                            .withType(CsvLine.class)
                            .withSeparator('\t')
                            .withSkipLines(3)
                            .build()
                            .parse();

                    for (CsvLine item : beans)
                    {
                        Path originalPath = file.toPath();
                        if(item.getValue().equals(2)
                        || item.getValue().equals(43)
                        || item.getValue().equals(32))
                        {
                            // Move here file into new subdirectory when file is invalid
                            Path copied = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/invalid_files");
                            try {
                                // Use resolve method to keep the "processed" as folder
                                br.close();
                                Files.move(originalPath, copied.resolve(originalPath.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                    }}
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Path originalPath = file.toPath();
            System.out.println(String.format("\nProcessed file : %s, moving the file to subfolder /processed\n",
                    originalPath));
        }

        // Move here file into new subdirectory when file processing is finished
                            Path copied = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/processed");
                            try {
                                // Use resolve method to keep the "processed" as folder
                                br.close();
                                Files.move(originalPath, copied.resolve(originalPath.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
    }
```

The problem is that I try to move a file. I get error:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\csv\nov\12_21_39.csv
>       at com.wordscore.engine.processor.DataValidationCheckJob.execute(DataValidationCheckJob.java:94)
>       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
>       at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
>     Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\csv\nov\12_21_39.csv
> ```

How I can edit the code in way that it can be moved properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have omitted `break;` after both `Files.move(originalPath, ...);` calls.

Without a `break` to exit the `for (CsvLine item : beans)` loop, processing continues over the next iteration. The second iteration will attempt to perform `Files.move(originalPath, ...)` again - and fails because the file has already been moved.

Therefore you get the `NoSuchFileException` which you have re-thrown as `RuntimeException` in your `try.. Files.move .. catch` block.

The handling would be cleaner if you dealt with move in one place and such that it avoids the untidy `br.close()`, leaving file handling to the auto-close `try()` block. Something like this:

```
Path invalidDir = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/invalid_files");
Path processedDir = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/processed");
for(File file : filesList) {

    Path originalPath = file.toPath();
    Path moveTo = processedDir.resolve(originalPath.getFileName());
    
    try (var br = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16)){
        List<CsvLine> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(br)
                .withType(CsvLine.class)
                .withSeparator('\t')
                .withSkipLines(3)
                .build()
                .parse();

        for (CsvLine item : beans) {
            if(item.getValue().equals(2)
            || item.getValue().equals(43)
            || item.getValue().equals(32)) {
                // file is invalid, skip it
                moveTo = invalidDir.resolve(originalPath.getFileName());
                // LOG MSG HERE
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    Files.move(originalPath, moveTo, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    System.out.format("%nProcessed file : %s, moving the file to subfolder %s%n", originalPath, moveTo);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the full code here, please?

Comment: Add `break;` after each `Files.move(originalPath, ...);`

Comment: I have one idea. is it possible to move the functionality for `Files.move(originalPath, ...);` outside of the loop `for (CsvLine item : beans)` and use Boolean flag to indicate to which directory at the end the file should be moved?

Comment: Correct - had added a outline which means only one `Files.move`.

Comment: I found one issue into the code. See the original post. Notice that if we find a value 32 for example the file will be moved which is correct. But after moving the file we want to continue with next file. I placed the code responsible for moving the file at the folder `/processes` at the end because in every way when the file is processed we want to move the file to `/processes` directory but I get again `Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your code above shows that a file with value 32 is moved to invalid, so if you try to move it to processed afterwards of course you will get `NoSuchFileException`. Perhaps you intend just to `Files.copy` to "invalid", and `Files.move` to "processed"?